# How to style a redux-tooltip?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I integrated the [redux-tooltip](https://github.com/kuy/redux-tooltip) in my application. Is there any way to apply my own styling? The Divs of the Tooltip-Component haven't any IDs or className, however they have a couple inline stylings.

https://github.com/kuy/redux-tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. submit an github issue to the author ask the `className` or `style` overwrite api, or
2. see what html it generates, then style it with your CSS solution.